# One physical server, Hyper-V, two IPs, two virtual servers (win + *nix)

Tags: hyper-v

I have one physical Windows 2008 server with Hyper-V installed. I also have IIS running on this physical machine and I'm fine with that.

I also have an additional IP address and I want to use it for CentOS. The way for me is to create virtual server with Hyper-V, and install CentOS.

But I can't figure out how to set up routing and link this additional IP address to CentOS with Hyper-V. I even can't do that with Windows XP on installed on virtual server.

It seems it's quite tricky and non-obvious cos I've spent more that 20 hours on that with no any results. I also googled for some documentation, but couldn't find what I need.

Would you be so kind to point me to some docs/papers where I can find information on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

When you installed Hyper-V you should have been asked to create a virtual network connection.  If you weren't, fire up the Hyper-V manager, highlight your server, and select Virtual Network Manager from the right-hand action panel.  From there create and External network.

Then, in the Hyper-V settings for your guest, connect the network adapter to the external network you just created.

Within CentOS, assign the IP address as normal.